# Jest mocking with react calling actual event handler after calling mock function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have this component test

```
    const component = mount(<MemoryRouter><Login/></MemoryRouter>);
    const emailField = component.find('input[type="email"]');
    const passwordField = component.find('input[type="password"]');
    const mockedSubmitFunction=jest.fn();
    component.find(Login).instance().onSubmit=mockedSubmitFunction;
    emailField.simulate('change', { target: { value: testEmail } });
    passwordField.simulate('change', { target: { value: testPassword } });
    component.find('form').simulate('submit');
    expect(mockedSubmitFunction).toBeCalled();
```

and in the component i have

in constructor :-

```
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
```

and the eventhandler

```
   onSubmit(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
```

when i put a breakpoint in onSubmit it is coming to the component function after executing the mocked onSubmit, why is this happening.

I assumed it will only call the mocked onSubmit.

What am I doing differently?

CodeSandbox :https://codesandbox.io/s/q95lv7vlrw

But the sandbox is showing Could not find module in path: 'object-inspect/util.inspect' relative to '/node_modules/object-inspect/index.js' for some reason, which is unrelated i guess

Comment: And in the component you have.. nothing? Could you provide a codesandox repro of your question?

Comment: @AndyTheos it has a render, but i have emitted it for simplicity, it just displays two fields username and password field with form  <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you got function mocked, but actual onSubmit is called. Instead if you want to call only mocked fn you have to provide it (as a prop in your test spec for example).

```
const mockedSubmitFunction = jest.fn(event => {
  console.log("Mocked function");
});
const component = mount(
  <MemoryRouter>
    <Login login={mockedSubmitFunction} />
  </MemoryRouter>
);
```

I [updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n5yvokz0l0) for you.

You can additionally check this [explained example on form testing](https://hackernoon.com/unit-testing-redux-connected-components-692fa3c4441c).

Update: i suppose that the actual problem OP has was that mock function was firing, but it was copied to instance, thus `expect...toBeCalled()` fails (actual mockedFn was not called). You can avoid these problems by passing mocked function as a prop, spying on a function, etc.

Comment: Hi @Andy  i have slight problem in the actual link i shared, when I comment out the email and password change events in test , the test is calling actual event handler, but when i have that only the mocked function is called. why is that ? https://codesandbox.io/s/0xn814y05v and the actual link I shared has the tests passed..

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/6n0wp17jyk
check this out, i guess you need to pass it like this, but not as `component.find(Login).instance().onSubmit = mockedSubmitFunction;`

Comment: Also i have updated the snip, now you can see the difference between `expect...toBeCalled` and the actual call results when i `expect..toEqual`.

Comment: when i do   componen.find(Login).instance().forceUpdate();  after assigning the mock the tests are passing though. https://codesandbox.io/s/6zrxj9n9r

Comment: The reason it worked with input changing and with `forceUpdate` is updating itself. You could go either with updating(not a fan of this) or with the method i mentioned.
Enzyme update for mount -http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/update.html,
Enzyme v3 docs -
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.md#for-mount-updates-are-sometimes-required-when-they-werent-before